# Create WMS service using MapServer

Tags: wms, mapserver

I am trying to create WMS service using Postgres data in MapServer, my map file (wms.map) is:

```
MAP
  EXTENT 8240841.450745 2400319.900386 9218007.463612 3107183.406947
  TRANSPARENT on
  IMAGETYPE png
  size 150 500
  web
    metadata
      "wms_title" "Customer Airports"
      "wms_onlineresource" "http://localhost:8085/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?"
      "wms_enable_request" "*"
      "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326 EPSG:900913"
      "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"
      "wms_format" "image/png"
    end
  end
  LAYER
      CONNECTIONTYPE postgis    
      CONNECTION "user=postgres password=abcd dbname=sample port=5432 host=localhost"
      DATA "geom FROM district_old using unique gid"
      STATUS Default
      TYPE polygon
      PROJECTION
         "init=epsg:900913"
      END 
      labelitem 'district'
      class                  
          style     
              outlinecolor 90 90 90
              width 2
          end 
          LABEL
             size 2
             BACKGROUNDCOLOR 255 201 14
             position auto
          END 
      end  
   END
END # nmtoken edit added missing Map END tag
```

When I paste in the browser this URL:

"http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=c://ms4w/apps/webgis/wms.map&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities" it is not displaying the XML file instead it is downloading a mapserv.exe file

Please correct my code.

Comment: Open the mapserver.exe file with a text editor. It contains the error message.

Comment: i am not getting any error message in xml file instead i am getting a warning as " WARNING: This layer has its status set to DEFAULT and will always be displayed when doing a GetMap request even if it is not requested by the client. This is not in line with the expected behavior of a WMS server. Using status ON or OFF is recommended. "

Comment: Does it help to change the ```STATUS DEFAULT``` to ```STATUS ON```?

Comment: no, i have changed status to ON then map is not displaying

Comment: What message do you get from http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=c://ms4w/apps/webgis/wms.map?

Comment: localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?mode=map&map=c://ms4w/apps/webgis/wms.map    with this url map is displaying

Comment: and without mode=map?

Comment: What version of MapServer are you using?

Comment: Is your data stored in EPSG:900913 projection?

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing here is an error response from MapServer. There is something wrong with your request or your service and MapServer is sending an error message.

The name of the error file is `mapserv.exe` it is a file of type application/vnd.ogc.se_xml, not a copy of the MapServer executable. If you open the file in a text editor you should see what the error is, otherwise you should look at your log files.

Whilst improving the code formatting of your question I noticed that the code posted is missing a closing `END` statement for the opening `MAP` statement.  Is this just a transcription error on your part, if not it then it's probably your error.